# Problems configuring Webscrab to intercept trafic from localhost(Webgoat)

Tags: web-browser, proxy

Problems configuring Webscrab to intercept traffic from localhost(Webgoat).

I am trying to go through the Webgoat tutorial and at one point I need to use Webscrap.
I configured the proxy though Firefox and I added the LAN settings in Windows, but it still doesn't work.

I can't find a solution on-line, I think I tried everything.

Firefox Configuration:
[image]

Windows LAN settings:

[image]

This is the file I run for Webgoat

[image]

This is the file I use for Webscrab
[image]

If I try to access the Webgoat through this link, webscrab does not intercept anything

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/WebGoat/attack
```

If I try to access webgoat through this link, the traffic is intercepted, however it says that the page is not found (Error 404)

```
http://127.0.0.1./webgoat/attack
```

I can't a solution on line so I hope here anybody knows how to make it work.

Thank you

Comment: in the firefox screenshot you have the default which is to bypass proxies for 127.0.0.1 . Try taking that out.

Comment: And I think you have to decide for one port: 8080 or 8008.

Comment: This is not a security issue, it is purely a configuration issue (as @Rook described below). Closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first sceenshot it says:

"**NO Proxy For**"  and it lists **127.0.0.1**  and **localhost**.

Then you are trying to access webgoat on localhost...  Perhaps you should look over your configurations more carefully in the future.